# How to use javascript code in arduino and assign javascript values to arduino values

Tags: javascript, c, arduino, webserver, iot

I'm creating an IoT project to send some commands to my Arduino board and receive some details through the internet.

After a lot of search, I recognized that the best solution for me is to convert arduino to a web-server and send requests to it.

I designed the showing page by:

```c
GSMServer server(80);
serer.begin();
GSMClient client = server.available();
client.println("HTML CODE HERE");
```

but I want to use javascript to parse receiving GET or POSTs and assign them to values in my code.

What should I do?

Comment: Neither running javascript on a classic Arduino nor serving substantial content from one will really be practical, unless you augment it with additional storage.  You should really try to keep the task of the Arduino to something like a very minimal RESTful API, and ideally use something simpler like a serial interface.  If you really want to put an embedded board on a network, chose instead something *designed* for that like an ESP8266 or something with an operating system like a router chip turned IoT board.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build upon GSMServer further so that it can handle different requests and respond different information based on the call.

Have you seen https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesWebServer

It shows how different calls can be made as well as how a http request can be responded with a html page.

Comment: ok, but how should I receive the requests? please explain more

Comment: Once you create the web server, you can make calls to it using GET or POST http requests and it will fetch you the response from the web server. For C based example look at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesWebClient . For javascript, check http methods - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp . For a more elaborate solution using Javascript to communicate to arduino, see the link https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/web-server-read-switch-using-AJAX/ . You will have to adapt it to use GSMServer instead of ethernet shield